# can't figure out where my syntax error is coming from

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a pretty small function here that I keep getting a syntax error for: "missing ; before statement". I've looked this over again and again and cannot figure out what I did wrong.

```
generate() {
 var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
 generateButton.onclick = addBox;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a ```function ``` before `generate`?

Comment: Does something come before this?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, when declaring functions you have to use the `function` keyword:

```
function generate() {
    var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
    generateButton.onclick = addBox;
}
```

You can also do like this:

```
var generate = function() {
    var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
    generateButton.onclick = addBox;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @jerome.s pointed, is important to rembember that, in the second declaration, the `generate` function can only be called **after** it's declared, whereas the first one doesn't have this requirement

Comment: Important to note the difference between those 2 declarations : to use `var generate = function() {}` , you can call it **only after** that you've declared it http://jsfiddle.net/kUBVu/

Answer (score 1):

missing keyword function and function definition for addBox

```
function generate() {
    var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
    generateButton.onclick = addBox;
}
function addBox()
{
    alert('button clicked');
}
```